# How to accept facebook cookies using python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, facebook, web-scraping, cookies

I have a problem clicking the facebook accept cookies button on [facebook creator studio website](https://business.facebook.com/creatorstudio/home). Cookies are shown only when the page is opened by the program, not when you open it manually.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\kocia\\OneDrive\\Plocha\\Python\\nastaveni\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://business.facebook.com/creatorstudio/?tab=instagram_content_posts')
```

Here is what i tried:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Přijmout vše']"))).click()
```

or

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="u_0_6_k1"]'))).click()
```

I found out, that for some reason the id changes every time.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Page above does not ask for cookies to accept.

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them. Use the API.

Comment: Duplicate of https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/18342/how-to-handle-dynamic-changing-ids-in-xpath

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the id changes randomly every time, but I found a workaround. Look at this snippet:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(string(), 'Allow essential and optional cookies')]")[0].click()
```

I use this **xpath**: `"//button[contains(string(), 'Allow essential and optional cookies')]"` it search for a button that contains the string *"Allow essential and optional cookies"*. In the main login page there is only one button that has this feature so I get the first element in the returned list `[0]` then it clicks it `click()`.